# In .Net 7.0 solution, is implicitly referenced Microsoft.NetCore.App 1.1.1 with security vulnerabilities a concern?

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, reference, nuget-package

I'm looking into a solution, which is using the latest .Net 7.0 framework, has an old nuget package (let's call it package X) with a dependency to `Microsoft.NetCore.App` version 1.1.1 with security vulnerabilities as shown in the screenshots below. In this case, the Microsoft library is only implicitly referenced.
[image]
[image]

I've searched for documentations or articles that could potentially explain the build behaviour of implicitly referenced library/package but no luck so far. Two things I'd like to know.

1. Does restoring package X would download the `Microsoft.NetCore.App` library during build?
2. Is this is a concern with the security vulnerabilities that could compromise the whole solution.
   Any confirmation would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It says "Microsoft.NetCore.App **larger or equal to** 1.1.1". The actual runtime will be 7.0 (there can't be more than one runtime in a process)

Comment: @PMF Having one runtime in a process makes sense. May I ask, even though `Microsoft.NetCore.App` version is so old, it still runs fine with the .Net 7.0 runtime? Meaning it's fully backward compatible?

Comment: For most cases, yes, the runtime should be backwards compatible. There are some breaking changes between runtime versions, but libraries are very rarely directly affected. Obviously, you'll need to test your application troughfully, but it's unlikely you'll run into problems not detected by testing.

Comment: @PMF Thanks for confirming that. Yup the application runs fine when it was upgraded to .Net 7.0.